# Unable to code sign the apache modules in mac

Tags: apache, dispatcher, codesign, macos-monterey, certificate-authority

I get the below error while starting Apache

```
root# sudo apachectl configtest
[Tue Jun 28 13:31:53.686521 2022] [so:error] [pid 8913] AH06665: No code signing authority for module at /private/libexec/apache2/mod_dispatcher.so specified in LoadModule directive.
httpd: Syntax error on line 191 of /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Code signing absent - not loading module at: /private/libexec/apache2/mod_dispatcher.so
```

To fix the above problem, I created **Certificate Authority** in mac machine by following - https://www.simplified.guide/macos/keychain-ca-code-signing-create and trying to codesign to sign the AEM Dispatcher module with below command

```
codesign --sign "XXX CA" --force --keychain ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db /private/libexec/apache2/mod_dispatcher.so
```

But I get the following error **The specified item could not be found in the keychain.**

Ref - https://www.codexpedia.com/apache-server/no-code-signing-authority-for-module-php-on-mac-monterey/

Can anyone tell me if there is any problem in above command ?

My macOS version is 12.2 (Monterey)

Comment: You need to
1. Create CA(You already done).
2. Create Certificate for code signing.
3. Use "codesign" command and then use Certificate that created from step 2.
You can see here https://www.simplified.guide/macos/keychain-cert-code-signing-create